# Asp.Net core 2.0: Detect Startup class invoked from migration or other ef operation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

At the current moment all default `Startup.cs` flow executed on every db related operation like droping db, adding migration, updating db to migrations, etc.

I have heavy app specific code in `Startup` which need to be invoked only if application run for real. So how could I detect that `Startup` class run from migration or other database related `dotnet` command.

Comment: You can add implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in you assembly and EF commands will use that to Create context instead of initialize services through Startup. That way you will have more control over what gets executed when running ef commands.

Comment: @Smit I have those factory and it's used to get a context, however for some reason standard starting pipeline still executed on every command and i change it to throw an exception now. So I see exception thrown and it's stack trace, however db operation like droping still executed fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as it was already noticed in comment to a question there is a `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` interface which need to be implemented to resolve `DbContext` at design time.

It could look somewhat like this:

```
public static class Programm{
    ...
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHostDuringGen(string[] args)
    {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<StartupGen>()  // <--- I'm just using different Startup child there where could be less complex code
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false).Build();
    }
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {   
        public MyDbContex CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            return Program.BuildWebHostDuringGen(args).Services.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        }
    }
```

However, due to some unclear reasons (I asked guys from Microsoft, but they don't explain this to me) `dotnet` currently on every operation implicitly call  `Programm.BuildWebHost` even if it's private - that's the reason why standard flow executed each time for the question's author. Workaround for that - **Rename** **`Programm.BuildWebHost`** to something else, like `InitWebHost`

There is an [issue created](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9076) for that, so maybe it will be resolved in 2.1 release on in future.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade) is still a bit unclear as to why this occurs. I've yet to find any concrete answer as to why it runs `Startup.Configure`. In 2.0 it's [recommend](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9033#issuecomment-317063370) to move any migration/seeding code to `Program.Main`. Here's an example by [bricelam](https://github.com/bricelam) on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9033#issuecomment-317104564).

```
public static IWebHost MigrateDatabase(this IWebHost webHost)
{
    using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        try
        {
            var db = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating the database.");
        }
    }

    return webHost;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args)
        .MigrateDatabase()
        .Run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Renaming BuildWebHost seems to prevent EF Migrations from calling it.